# three.js Cube Geometry - how to update parameters?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Possibly dumb question but here goes. Three.js geometries have 'parameter' feilds associated with them, see the box geometry here...

[box Geometry parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7BU0.png)

I am trying to update these parameters like this...

```
var nodeSize = 10;
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(nodeSize, nodeSize, nodeSize);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({side:THREE.DoubleSide}));

scene.add(mesh);
mesh.geometry.parameters.depth=20;
```

But of course, the geometry remains unchanged. Is there a way of updating the geometry by editing these parameters?

fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/kn3owveg/2/

Any help appreciated!

Comment: what are you trying to do by changing the `depth` field? that information could be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your help @Giovazz89, I have made a fiddle from the answers received https://jsfiddle.net/henryJack/kn3owveg/6/

Comment: ... NOT a dumb question by any measure

Comment: I would use geometry reassignment rather than scaling, for details on how this is achieved see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaitat is totally right, you can't change geometry with changing of `parameters`.

And there can be another solution. With scaling of your cube.

```
function setSize( myMesh, xSize, ySize, zSize){
  scaleFactorX = xSize / myMesh.geometry.parameters.width;
  scaleFactorY = ySize / myMesh.geometry.parameters.height;
  scaleFactorZ = zSize / myMesh.geometry.parameters.depth;
  myMesh.scale.set( scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY, scaleFactorZ );
}
...
setSize(mesh, 10, 10, 20);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/e3g99j6v/) example

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have made this from your answer https://jsfiddle.net/henryJack/kn3owveg/6/

Comment: "Totally right" may be a little bit incorrect. :) As the threeJS API stands now, the answer is likely to be correct. But this is open source. I think the answer to OP should be "yes, there is a way to do this... it may take a feature request and some time." So can you please clarify/expand. Is there something you know about this problem that makes it impossible ?

Comment: @kandinski Well, you can prove the incorrectness with providing a working example where you directly change values of [`.parameters`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry.parameters) of `THREE.BoxGeometry()` and it affects the geometry :)

Comment: Im ambitious but not deaf...you kindly reveled the end of that challenge in your tone. Exactly what I was looking for...saved me days of pointless effort. Thing is Im feeding the parametric api some basic algorithms and I'm mesmerized by the beauty of the... things... what do you call them? Blown away. And I want to tweak the algos in real time to find right ranges for the sweet spots... what do you call *them* ? I looked at your bio... you know what Im after. So I could either pose the most ridiculous question ever posted on SO or invite you to respond side channel... prefer later.

Comment: @kandinski TBH, I didn't get what you want to tell me :) If you have questions, you can also ask them on the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/) with more detailed explanation.

Comment: thank you for the invitation. I will follow up there and ping you with an example when I clean things up a bit. Thanks again.

Comment: Technically scaling only creates the illusion of an updated geometry. I would say a better approach would be geometry reassignment, for details on how this is achieved see my answer.

Comment: With the above mentioned approach you can update any aspect of the geometry including depth segments for example. This is especially useful when working with non cube geometries like cylinders or spheres.

Answer (score 1):

`parameters.depth` is only used at geometry construction time. it has no effect when modifying it. you can think of it as `read only`.

Use the example at [BoxGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/BoxGeometry) and the gui on the right to see how to achieve what you want.

Comment: True that geometry parameters are only used at construction time. The linked example is using geometry reassignment. For details on how this is achieved see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, scaling only creates the illusion of an updated geometry. I would say a better approach would be to reassign the geometry value of your mesh to a new geometry.

```js
mesh.geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(newSize, newSize, newSize)
```

**With this approach you can update any aspect of the geometry including depth segments for example.** This is especially useful when working with non cube geometries like cylinders or spheres.

Here is a full rework of your original code using this approach, really only the last line has changed:

```js
var nodeSize = 10;
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(nodeSize, nodeSize, nodeSize);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({side:THREE.DoubleSide}));

scene.add(mesh);
mesh.geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(nodeSize, nodeSize, 20);
```